# How do I store a rating in a song?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, database, winforms

I want to be able to store information about a song that has been opened using my application. I would like for the user to be able to give the song a rating and this rating be loaded every time the users opens that file using my application.

I also need to know whether I should store the ratings in a database or an xml file.

Comment: Anytime! I would recommend retitling this question to something like "How do I store a rating in a song?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[C# ID3 Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/) is a .Net class library for editing id3 tags (v1-2.4). I would store the ratings directly into the comments section of the mp3 since id3v1 does not have many of the storage features that id3v2 does. If you want to store additional information for each mp3, what about placing a unique identifier on the mp3 and then having that do a database lookup?

I would be cautious about adding custom tags to mp3s as it is an easy way to ruin a large library. Also, I have gone down this road before and while I enjoyed the programming knowledge that came out of it, trying something like the iTunes SDK or Last FM might be a better route.

Comment: Thanks! I had already downloaded the C# ID3 Lib, but didn't think about using the comments as a way to save the rating. This also allows me to use a better rating system then just 1-5.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a single-file, zero-config database.  [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) in your case.

I don't think XML is a good idea.  XML shines in data *interchange* and storing very small amounts of information.  In this case a user may rate thousands of tracks ( I have personally in online radios that allow ratings), and you may have lots of other information to store about the track.

Export and import using XML export procedures if you have to.  Don't use it as your main datastore.

Comment: Sqlite is another popular single-file, zero-config database.

Answer (score 2):

I would store it in a file as it is easier to keep with the mp3 file itself. If all you're doing is storing ratings, would you consider setting the ID3 rating field instead?

Comment: Could you provide some more info on the ID3 rating field? (Specificlly how to change and save it using C#)

Answer (score 1):

For this type of very simple storage I don't think it really matters all that much. The pro's of XML is its very easy to deploy and its editable outside of your app. the con's are, its editible outside your application (could be good, could be bad, depends on your situation)

Maybe another option (just because you can ;-) is an OODBMS, check out [DB4Objects](http://www.db4o.com/), its seriously addictive and very, very cool.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier it is better to store such information in media file itself. And my suggestion is to use [TagLib#](http://taglib.github.io/) lib for this (best media metadata lib I can find). Very powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the ratings in a XML file, that way it's easy to edit from the outside, easy to read in .NET and you don't have to worry about shipping a database for something simple with you application.

Something like this might work for you:

```
<Songs>
  <Song Title="{SongTitle}">
    <Path>{Song path}</Path>
    <Rating>3</Rating>
  </Song>
</Songs>
```

Comment: In XML attributes use = and must be quoted. Element tags are case sensitve ("</songs>").

Answer (score 0):

If the song format supports suitable meta data (eg. MP3), then follow Kevin's advice of using the meta data. This is by far the best way of doing it, and it is what the meta data is intended for.

If not, then it really depends on your application. If you want to share the rating information - especially over a web service, then I would go for XML: it would be trivial to supply your XML listings as one big feed, for example.

XML (or most other text formats) also have the advantage that they can be easily edited by a human in a text editor.

The database would have its advantages if you had a more closed system, you wanted speed and fast indexing, and/or have other tables you might want to store as well (eg. data about albums and bands).